# Total Registered Users Count

Tags: php, mysql

What's the most efficient way of counting the total number of registered users on a website?

I was thinking of using the following query, but if this table contained 1000's of users, the execution time will be very long.

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
```

Instead, I thought of creating a separate table that will hold this value. Each time a new user registers, or a current one deleted, this value gets updated.

**My Question:**

Is it possible to carry out an INSERT and UPDATE in one query? - The INSERT will be for storing the new users details, and the UPDATE to increment the total users value.

I'm very interested in your thoughts on this.

If there is a better and faster way to find out the total registered users, I'm very interested to know ;

Cheers ;)

Comment: Slow for just 1000 rows??? No way!

Comment: Oops. Maybe I should have added a couple more 00's ;)

Comment: I don't specifically know about MySQL but as long as the table has at least one index then the SQL engine can use it to optimise COUNT(*).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) to update the value every time you make an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE.

> if this table contained 1000's of users, the execution time will be very long.

I doubt that it would be that slow for *thousands* of users. If you had *millions* of users then it would probably be too slow.

And does your count need to be 100% accurate?

> If an approximate row count is sufficient, [`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-table-status.html) can be used.

[(Source)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

By the way, if you are using MyISAM then your original query will be close to instant because the row count is stored already with this storage engine.

Comment: It would be better if it could be accurate?

Answer (score 0):

You don't do an insert and update in one query. but rather, you do them in one "Transaction".

Transactions have a concept of "atomicity", which means that other processes cannot see "part" of the transaction - it is all or nothing.

If this concept is not familiar to you, you may wish to look it up.